# How do I use mysql_connect() and mysql_select_db() correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Yes, I know `mysql_connect()` is deprecated, but I'm using it for learning purposes.

I have a little Raspberry Pi server set up, using Nginx and Raspbian, and I downloaded a PHP script to serve as a login handler, except that I can't seem to connect to my MySQL database.

Here's what I have:

```
define ("DB_HOST", "localhost"); <-- Don't know what I'm doing here
define ("DB_USER", mysql.default_username);
define ("DB_PASS", mysql.default_password);
define ("DB_NAME", "database_name_i_dunno"); <-- I don't know...

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link) or die("Couldn't select database.");
```

The way it's set up currently,  this script is loaded, I get "Couldn't make connection."

I also have a MySQL file, and if I replace `"database_name_i_dunno"` with `"dbsql.sql"` it still does nothing to remedy the situation. Wut do?

Comment: why learn something which is deprecated? surely it would make more sense to learn the newer driver so you don't have to learn as much?

Comment: Well, you can begin with turning on error reporting and setting it to display everything. In your php.ini file set `error_reporting` to `-1`, and `display_errors` to `1`. Then restart your server.

Comment: @DanielMorgan I'm just trying to get it to work before I optimize it.

Comment: @SuperCheezGi There is no point in "optimizing" a library which is going to be removed from future PHP revision.. Unless you are working on a "legacy"/old version of PHP, you should use 5.4, and not 5.5.. If you just wanna create something for the hell of it... Learn PDO or MySQLi

Comment: Come on guys. He knows the mysql extension is deprecated. Stop pestering him/her.

Comment: @DarylGill I'm trying to make it work before I switch to another library. _Happy?_

Comment: Don't you even know the name of the database you are trying to connect to? Are you sure that MySQL is installed and running?

Comment: @SuperCheezGi Prior knowledge for MySQL is not required for MySQLi for example, it's a complete different procedure

Comment: Which web server do you use on your raspberry? lighttpd? Apache? Maybe it would be a good idea to create an info.php to check which system and which components are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`localhost`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/localhost) is an alias for the loopback IP address `127.0.0.1`. In other words, `localhost` is another word for "this computer" (i.e. the computer you are sitting at right now).

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); // Points back to this computer
```

The username and password values in your code need to be fixed. First of all, strings have to be enclosed in quotes (single or double). Second, in order to get PHP's INI settings you need to use the `ini_get()` function:

```
define('DB_USER', ini_get('mysql.default_username'));
define('DB_PASS', ini_get('mysql.default_password'));
```

The database name is the name of the database (!) that you want to work with. If you use phpMyAdmin then there should be a dropdown menu on the left side of the screen where you can select databases. The names in that dropdown menu are also the names you need to use in your PHP scripts.

```
define('DB_NAME', 'database_name_i_dunno');
```

These look to be okay.

```
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link) or die("Couldn't select database.");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function looks correct, but if you get couldn't make connection, you have your problem there. Localhost is the current host, you can replace it with 127.0.0.1. Did you installed your mysql server already? 
I guess you have not so do first this:

```
apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client php5-mysql
```

After that you can install phpmyadmin as well, then it's easier for you to handle your databases:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql phpmyadmin
```

Now you can create your database.

Here is a quick video, that can probably help you:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_c018_lhHQ

(try to use the mysqli or pdo API, both are easier than the old mysql API.